# Fungus gnat larvae on chili plant?

Tags: pests

Had a few chilly plants. Recently, one of them started looking a bid sad and droopy. When I watered it today there were some maggots coming out the drainage holes. I think they are fungus gnat larvae but I'm not 100% sure so I'm posting here to check. Pictures attached.

Small ones are the dead ones, big one was still alive.

[image]

Thanks a lot!